# Amfphp BackOffice Reports Flash Player is Needed When Installed

Tags: installation, flash, amfphp

I have created a second website on a Windows 2008 server and added the Amfphp 2.2.1 folder. I can view the BackOffice page in the local browser but when I go to the ServiceBrowser page it reports that Flash Player is needed. I have installed Flash Player and viewed Flash content to prove to myself it is working. Can anyone explain how to solve this please?

Chris

Comment: This might be any number of things, unfortunately. Have you seen it work with your browser? Is this a server I can look at, in which case you can post a url with a login so I can have a look? Most likely it's an issue with your browser. I can tell you where the relevant code, if that helps: BackOffice/js/sb.js, line 67

Comment: To try and continue developing I moved to my Windows 7 computer. I configured IIS7, created a new website, fresh install of PHP, Flash Player and Amfphp. I browsed to the default BackOffice page and it displays fine. When I click on the ServiceBrowser link I see the ServiceBrowser page but no services and the warning 'Flash Player is needed to make AMF calls.' below step 3 Call the Server.

Comment: Ok, let's try this: Go to http://arielsommeria.com/amfphp2.2.1/BackOffice/SignIn.php, login a/a, and please tell me if you see the same warning

Comment: Hello Ariel. Thank you for looking at this. I can view your ServiceBrowser with no problems! So what does this mean?

Comment: Ariel - Some more information. If I browse to your URL using IE9 and login I get the same error, no services listed and under the buttons in '3. Call the server' it says Flash Player is needed to make AMF calls. However if I repeat this using Chrome all is fine. If I browse to my Service, on the same web server, I get 'HTTP Error 500.0 Internal Server Error'.

Comment: If your browser works with my server, it means your browser is ok. So stick to chrome now to keep things simple. Now, to your 500 error, this means that PHP tripped up somewhere. You now need to investigate that error. See http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/documentation/troubleshooting-and-debugging-your-project/ , specifically the paragraph labelled "Getting information about PHP errors" at the bottom

Comment: I'll look into it. Thank you. Would you mind if I sketched out what I am trying to achieve in a short email please? I want to be sure I am developing my application using Amfphp appropriately.

Comment: OK, I edited my PHP.ini file to temporarily display any PHP errors and it showed that Amfphp couldn't find DiscoveryServices. I looked in the Plugins folder and it wasn't there so I copied the AmfphpDiscovery folder in from the original downloaded files and I can now see the services! Can I still drop you a brief email please?

Comment: That's not possible as I understand on stackoverflow. Leave me a comment on my website arielsommeria.com/blog/, on the about page, and I'll get back to you.